# QGIS Custom Qt Widgets on OSX

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, development

When I install QGIS on windows I get a bunch of custom widgets in  Qt Designer

[image: Custom Widgets]

On OSX I can't figure out how to get those same widgets to appear in Qt Designer. I have set my environment variables according to [installation instructions by KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis) as so:

```
export PATH=/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Python/2.7/site-packages:/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python
```

But no luck. Has anyone else gotten this to work?